# Why does printing content with column-count get displaced in Chrome when using table headers and footers?

Tags: google-chrome, printing, html-table, multiple-columns

I am trying to improve my print stylesheet, and want repeated headers on each page. The obvious way to do this is to present my content in a table, as table headers and footers will automatically repeated.

However, doing this causes any `column-count: 2` content inside the body of my table to get shifted down in the rendered PDF (note: not visible when emulating print media).

Why is this?

```
<!doctype HTML>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>

<table>
    <thead><tr><td>some header</td></tr></thead>
    <tfoot><tr><td>some footer</td></tr></tfoot>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td style="display: block">
            <div>
            <p>
                Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32.  The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham.
            </p>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<style>
    html, body, table {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }

    thead {
        background-color: red;
    }

    tfoot {
        background-color: blue;
    }

    tbody {
        background-color: green;
    }

    tbody tr {
        height: 1000px;
    }

    p {
        column-count: 2;
    }
</style>
<script>

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/2p943n7a/

Screenshot of print preview (gap highlighted in blue):
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been confirmed to be a Chrome bug:

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=866408#c2

There is no such offset when printing on Firefox.